# Kohana Routing Issue

Tags: php, routes, kohana, kohana-3

I know that there are countless threads about this, but I would appreciate a quick pointer to explain what I am missing here. I have a controller called `Controller_Index_Orders` which resides in `/conroller/orders/index.php`. It has one method `action_index()`. I then have the following Route code for it:

```
Route::set('orders', 'orders(/<action>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'orders',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

When I go to `baseUrl/orders/` or `baseUrl/orders` I am getting a 404. What am I missing here?

EDIT:

Controller_Orders is now in /controllers/orders.php Route as follows:

```
Route::set('orders', 'orders(/<action>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'orders',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Going to baseUrl/orders or baseUrl/orders/ still not functioning.

EDIT2:

Default Route.

Route::set('default', '((/(/)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your naming is all screwed up. If you have a controller called `Controller_Index_Orders` it should reside in `classes/controller/index/orders.php`. You'll also need to specify the proper controller in your route: `'controller' => 'index_orders'`. You might have to throw a `directory` key in there too.

Comment: So does it make sense to have a controller called Controller_Orders that would deal with url baseUrl/orders/? Or is that bad form?

Comment: I would make it Controller_Orders. I have no idea why you have the Index in there, I'm just telling you how to make it work with your current naming scheme.

Comment: And the filename would be orders.php in /controllers? Sorry, just starting, and need to get the standard directory structure down.

Comment: `application/controller/orders.php`

`Class Controller_Orders extends Controller{}`

Comment: I have the documentation open right now. Unfortunately, it is far from being comprehensive for a new user, although a very good introduction for people who are probably already familiar with PHP MVC.

Comment: Edited, with new configuration. Does that look better in terms of style? Also, do you spot the remaining bug? Also, just noticed your Chrono Trigger guy, very nice!

Comment: It needs to be in `application/controller/orders.php` not `application/controllers/orders.php`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, apologies for the wasted time. In any case, if I comment out that route, and leave only the default shown above, shouldn't `baseUrl/orders/` or `baseUrl/orders` get routed to `controller/orders.php` with the classname `Controller_Orders`?

Comment: I figured out the issue was that 'index_file' setting in kohana initialization was set to FALSE (changed it to index.php). I do not understand why that was messing with the routing, but now everything is working as expected. Thanks for your help and for contributing to the framework.